# Sending time with timezone from PHP to flash

Tags: php, flash, datetime

I am trying to send the time to flash but set to the currently timezone. When you view the below even though the echo date, looks like its working the `$time` is the same. When i test in flash I get the extra hour added. Any help tips welcome on this one...

```
$format = "d/m/Y H:m:s";
$timezone = "Europe/Amsterdam";
date_default_timezone_set($timezone);

echo "<h1>Timezone ".$timezone."</h1>";
$date = date($format);
echo "<h3>Date: ".$date."<h3>";
$time = strtotime($date);
echo "<h3>Time: ".$time."<h3>";
$date2 = date($format, $time);
echo "<h3>Reverse: ".$date2."<h3>";


$timezone = "Europe/London";
date_default_timezone_set($timezone);

echo "<h1>Timezone ".$timezone."</h1>";
$date = date($format);
echo "<h3>Date: ".$date."<h3>";
$time = strtotime($date);
echo "<h3>Time: ".$time."<h3>";
$date2 = date($format, $time);
echo "<h3>Reverse: ".$date2."<h3>";


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the PHP time() object for this? Pass this value:

```
time()."000" // note the trailing zeroes
```

Call that serverTime and pass it as a query string:

```
echo "myFlashFile.swf?serverTime=".time()."000";
```

Then in your Actionscript:

```
myDate = new Date();
myDate.setTime(serverTime);
```

Comment: I need to know the time in that particular timezone

Answer (score 0):

Would some sort of mathematics solve the day? ie:

```
$time = date("U")+date("Z");
```

This would work for the timezone ahead, but not so good for behind